# Access SQL db from mobile app

Tags: iphone, sql-server, web-services, wcf, security

I'm building a mobile front-end for my customer's CRM system. CRM data is stored in a SQL Server database in their local network. What will be the best practice to make this data available to mobile app users. Mobile app will be distributed using Enterprise key, not via App Store.

I'm thinking about making a WCF service running on a local server and having access to the SQL server via ethernet. This service will provide basic authentication. But I'm not sure if it's the best way in terms of security.

How to provide access to SQL server data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WCF web service can definitely be used as a SQL front end. Windows or JavaScript-based client applications running on hand-held devices have no trouble accessing WCF applications, and there's plenty of sample code out there about using a WCF app as a front-end to databases. Here's a sample project from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405189/How-to-access-SQL-database-from-an-iPhone-app-Via).

Security wise, there are several options: you could create a Login(ID, PWD) function that all non-authenticated user requests would have to pass through before getting to your SQL server. Once the  user authenticates, you can create a persistant session or send back to the client a SessionID he/she can use to re-authenticate on subsequent requests. You can also use more exotic and complex methods for authentication/authorization like client certificates and Forms, though on a iOS or Android device that will certainly take some extra work.

Since a public web service, accessing company core data, is a hacker's dream, you can always set up your web service so that it can only be accessed from inside the company firewalls via VPN. If not that, then you can use SSL or message-level encryption.